# Get access token without user invention for known account using Youtube API

Tags: php, youtube-data-api, google-oauth

I am developing application in PHP. I will allow the users to schedule live streaming from my application using Youtube API using the common account.

The problem is i don't want to share the password of this account to users.

Once the user come to my web application the user automatically authorize to google account and get access token without user invention.Is it possible.i juts done some coding from my end.But here I am using user to give email and password for account authentication.

```
<?php

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();
//'2015-08-28T00:00:00.000Z'
//'2015-08-29T00:00:00.000Z'
/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var datefield=document.createElement("input")
    datefield.setAttribute("type", "date")
    if (datefield.type!="date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
        document.write('<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n')
        document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"><\/script>\n')
        document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>\n') 
    }
</script>

<script>
if (datefield.type!="date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
    jQuery(function($){ //on document.ready
        $('.dateStart').datepicker();
        $('.dateEnd').datepicker();
    })
}
</script>

 <?php

$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'dsfsfsdfofgm9e4uvg.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'dsfsdfdsfPhf55tcCDLu';
$htmlBody="";
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}


// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['timeStart']) && isset($_POST['timeEnd']) && isset($_POST['Status']) && isset($_POST['dateStart']) && isset($_POST['dateEnd']))
{
  try {

    // Create an object for the liveBroadcast resource's snippet. Specify values
    // for the snippet's title, scheduled start time, and scheduled end time.
    $startTime  = $_POST['dateStart']."T".$_POST['timeStart'].":00+0530";
    $endTime  = $_POST['dateEnd']."T".$_POST['timeEnd'].":00+0530";
    //$startDatetime = new DateTime($startTime);
    //$endDatetime = new DateTime($endTime);

    //$startDatetime = $startDatetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
    //$endDatetime = $endDatetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
    $broadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
    $broadcastSnippet->setTitle($_POST['title']);
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime($startTime);
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledEndTime($endTime);

    // Create an object for the liveBroadcast resource's status, and set the
    // broadcast's status to "private".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus();
    $status->setPrivacyStatus($_POST['Status']);

    // Create the API request that inserts the liveBroadcast resource.
    $broadcastInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();
    $broadcastInsert->setSnippet($broadcastSnippet);
    $broadcastInsert->setStatus($status);
    $broadcastInsert->setKind('youtube#liveBroadcast');

    // Execute the request and return an object that contains information
    // about the new broadcast.
    $broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,status',
        $broadcastInsert, array());

    // Create an object for the liveStream resource's snippet. Specify a value
    // for the snippet's title.
    $streamSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStreamSnippet();
    $streamSnippet->setTitle('New Stream');

    // Create an object for content distribution network details for the live
    // stream and specify the stream's format and ingestion type.
    $cdn = new Google_Service_YouTube_CdnSettings();
    $cdn->setFormat("1080p");
    $cdn->setIngestionType('rtmp');

    // Create the API request that inserts the liveStream resource.
    $streamInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStream();
    $streamInsert->setSnippet($streamSnippet);
    $streamInsert->setCdn($cdn);
    $streamInsert->setKind('youtube#liveStream');

    // Execute the request and return an object that contains information
    // about the new stream.
    $streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->insert('snippet,cdn',
        $streamInsert, array());

    // Bind the broadcast to the live stream.
    $bindBroadcastResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->bind(
        $broadcastsResponse['id'],'id,contentDetails',
        array(
            'streamId' => $streamsResponse['id'],
        ));

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Your Broadcast success fully scheduled.</h3><ul>";
   $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s published at %s (%s)</li>',
        $broadcastsResponse['snippet']['title'],
        $broadcastsResponse['snippet']['publishedAt'],
        $broadcastsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Added Stream</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $streamsResponse['snippet']['title'],
        $streamsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Bound Broadcast</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>Broadcast (%s) was bound to stream (%s).</li>',
        $bindBroadcastResponse['id'],
        $bindBroadcastResponse['contentDetails']['boundStreamId']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    //$htmlBody .="<h3>Live  Broadcast</h3><div>";

    //$htmlBody .= sprintf("<iframe id='ytplayer' type='text/html' width='640' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%s?autoplay=1'  frameborder='0'></iframe>",
        //  $broadcastsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</div>';


  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
      // echo $e->getMessage();
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  } else {
  if(isset($_GET['propid']))
  {
  $projectname = $_GET['name'];
  $htmlBody = <<<END
   <form action="" method="post">
  <label>Event Title:  $projectname</label>
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="$projectname"/><br/><br/>
 <label>Start Time:</label>
<input type="date" name="dateStart"/>
 <select name="timeStart">
  <option value="00:00">12:00 AM</option>
  <option value="00:30">12:30 AM</option>
  <option value="01:00">01 AM</option>
  <option value="01:30">01:30 AM</option>
  <option value="02:00">02:00 AM</option>
  <option value="02:30">02:30 AM</option>
  <option value="03:00">03:00 AM</option>
  <option value="03:30">03:30 AM</option>
  <option value="04:00">04:00 AM</option>
  <option value="04:30">04:30 AM</option>
  <option value="05:00">05:00 AM</option>
  <option value="05:30">05:30 AM</option>
  <option value="06:00">06:00 AM</option>
  <option value="06:30">06:30 AM</option>
  <option value="07:00">07:00 AM</option>
  <option value="07:30">07:30 AM</option>
  <option value="08:00">08:00 AM</option>
  <option value="08:30">08:30 AM</option>
  <option value="09:00">09:00 AM</option>
  <option value="09:30">09:30 AM</option>
  <option value="10:00">10:00 AM</option>
  <option value="10:30">10:30 AM</option>
  <option value="11:00">11:00 AM</option>
  <option value="11:30">11:30 AM</option>
  <option value="12:00">12:00 PM</option>
  <option value="12:30">12:30 PM</option>
  <option value="13:00">01:00 PM</option>
  <option value="13:30">01:30 PM</option>
  <option value="14:00">02:00 PM</option>
  <option value="14:30">02:30 PM</option>
  <option value="15:00">03:00 PM</option>
  <option value="15:30">03:30 PM</option>
  <option value="16:00">04:00 PM</option>
  <option value="16:30">04:30 PM</option>
  <option value="17:00">5:00 PM</option>
  <option value="17:30">5:30 PM</option>
  <option value="18:00">6:00 PM</option>
  <option value="18:30">6:30 PM</option>
  <option value="19:00">7:00 PM</option>
  <option value="19:30">7:30 PM</option>
  <option value="20:00">8:00 PM</option>
  <option value="20:30">8:30 PM</option>
  <option value="21:00">9:00 PM</option>
  <option value="21:30">9:30 PM</option>
  <option value="22:00">10:00 PM</option>
  <option value="22:30">10:30 PM</option>
  <option value="23:00">11:00 PM</option>
  <option value="23:30">11:30 PM</option>
  </select>
<br/><br/>
 <label>End Time:</label>
<input type="date" name="dateEnd"/>
 <select name="timeEnd">
  <option value="00:00">12:00 AM</option>
  <option value="00:30">12:30 AM</option>
  <option value="01:00">01 AM</option>
  <option value="01:30">01:30 AM</option>
  <option value="02:00">02:00 AM</option>
  <option value="02:30">02:30 AM</option>
  <option value="03:00">03:00 AM</option>
  <option value="03:30">03:30 AM</option>
  <option value="04:00">04:00 AM</option>
  <option value="04:30">04:30 AM</option>
  <option value="05:00">05:00 AM</option>
  <option value="05:30">05:30 AM</option>
  <option value="06:00">06:00 AM</option>
  <option value="06:30">06:30 AM</option>
  <option value="07:00">07:00 AM</option>
  <option value="07:30">07:30 AM</option>
  <option value="08:00">08:00 AM</option>
  <option value="08:30">08:30 AM</option>
  <option value="09:00">09:00 AM</option>
  <option value="09:30">09:30 AM</option>
  <option value="10:00">10:00 AM</option>
  <option value="10:30">10:30 AM</option>
  <option value="11:00">11:00 AM</option>
  <option value="11:30">11:30 AM</option>
  <option value="12:00">12:00 PM</option>
  <option value="12:30">12:30 PM</option>
  <option value="13:00">01:00 PM</option>
  <option value="13:30">01:30 PM</option>
  <option value="14:00">02:00 PM</option>
  <option value="14:30">02:30 PM</option>
  <option value="15:00">03:00 PM</option>
  <option value="15:30">03:30 PM</option>
  <option value="16:00">04:00 PM</option>
  <option value="16:30">04:30 PM</option>
  <option value="17:00">5:00 PM</option>
  <option value="17:30">5:30 PM</option>
  <option value="18:00">6:00 PM</option>
  <option value="18:30">6:30 PM</option>
  <option value="19:00">7:00 PM</option>
  <option value="19:30">7:30 PM</option>
  <option value="20:00">8:00 PM</option>
  <option value="20:30">8:30 PM</option>
  <option value="21:00">9:00 PM</option>
  <option value="21:30">9:30 PM</option>
  <option value="22:00">10:00 PM</option>
  <option value="22:30">10:30 PM</option>
  <option value="23:00">11:00 PM</option>
  <option value="23:30">11:30 PM</option>
  </select>
<br/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="Status" value="unlisted"/>
 <!--<label>Stream Status:</label>
 <select name="Status">
  <option value="public">Public</option>
  <option value="unlisted">Unlisted</option>
  <option value="private">Private</option>
</select> <br/><br/>-->
<label>Participants:</label>
<input type="text" name="emails" placeholder="Comma separated emails"/><br/><br/>
<input type ="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
END;
} else {

 $htmlBody = <<<END
 <p>Close this window and click the schedule button for live streaming</p>
<p>You need to <a href="#"  onclick="window.close();">Close Window</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;

}

}
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl" onclick="window.open('$authUrl', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=400'); return false;">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bound Live Broadcast</title>
</head>
<body>

  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

How can change this code to get access token to automatically. Please suggest.

Comment: I’m not clear on what you’re trying to do: Do you want to use the YouTube API for this account on the server side without user authorization or do you want to *log in the user on YouTube*? Because that’s not possible.

Comment: Once we get access token after user login then only we can use YouTube API. Now I am giving login popup in above code  to users login the common account and getting the access token. I need to get the access token without giving email id and password because this account is known account(Common for all users). I need to authorize the user Automatically for access YouTube API without user invention?Is it possible?Make sense?

Comment: I used service account to get access token automatically.But the service account will not work for the youtube API.